# What is the location of CURAND library in CUDA 2.3

Tags: cuda

I am writing a code which uses CURAND library but when I compile I get an error stating No such File or Directory. When I went to the location /usr/local/cuda/lib64 I could not find the library there. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, CURAND wasn't available until CUDA 3.2, so you'll need to upgrade to a newer version of the CUDA toolkit to use it. The current production release is CUDA 4.2, and the CUDA 5 Release Candidate is available now as well:

http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-downloads

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to test my code using device emulator which is not present in CUDA 4.2.